# Extract search phrase from Google URL

Tags: google-sheets, extract

I am trying to create a cell which shows the terms that people search for on Google. We can get this data from another cell which has the referring URL, in this format:
http://www.google.com/afs/ads?q=chemical%20store&oe=utf-8&ie=utf-8

What formula should I use to get the text between "q=" and "&"?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps (using A1 as our example URL cell):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(LEFT(A1, FIND("&", A1) - 1), LEN(LEFT(A1, FIND("&", A1))) - FIND("=", A1) - 1), "%20", " ")
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric! When I do that I get this error (screenshot):
http://prntscr.com/d8lfr5

The formula you typed contains an error.
• To get assistance in entering a function, click OK,then click Function on the Insert menu.
• If you are not trying to enter a formula, avoid using an equal sign (=) or minus sign (-), or precede it with a single quotation mark (').

Comment: Sorry, I had written it on mobile. It is fixed now.